# How to read stdin in gstreamer on Windows?

Tags: gstreamer

I've found that the standard way to feed gstreamer with data from another application is to launch gstreamer with

```
gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! ...
```

and push the data to gstreamer's stdin.

But I've found out that `fdsrc` plugin is missing on the Windows build of gstreamer. Is there some equivalent source element for Windows?

Or is there some other way to feed the data to gstremer on Windows? Something like named pipes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

GStreamer has a plugin called 'appsrc' which can be used to feed data to pipelines from external applications.

Similarly there is a 'appsink' can be used to output data from GStreamer pipelines to external applications.

[appsrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsrc.htmlhttp://)

[example](https://gist.github.com/nzjrs/725122/16ceee88aafae389bab207818e0661328921e1ab)